# Android ListView with Multiline TextView a Space Line

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, textview

list_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAdi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/DarkGreen"
         />
```

activity_main.xml like this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listselector" >
</ListView>
```

My list show:

```
sample text 1
-------------------
sample multiline
text 2


--------------------
sample text 3
--------------------
```

When textview be multiline like 2, there is a space line. I dont want to space line.
I want to like this:

```
sample text 1
-------------------
sample multiline
text 2
--------------------
sample text 3
--------------------
```

list adapter:

```
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_layout, c, from, to, 10);

            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can you paste your list adapter code?

Comment: I added list adapter code

Comment: Make sure your text data doesn't contain new line ('\n') symbol at the end.

Comment: There is not new line symbol

Comment: I copied your code and it's giving me a good result. I think you should consider your cursor, it's probably putting a new line to the end or something, try printing out those multiline items to see if there's something at the end of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAdi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/DarkGreen"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
         />
```

I added to textview android:maxLines="2" and android:ellipsize="end" then looks like this:

```
sample text 1
-------------------
sample multiline
text 2...
--------------------
sample text 3
--------------------
```

So I want to show max two lines, if text longer than two lines appends three points.
This is the likely solution.